# Kiwi-TCMS. <Errno 99. Cannot assign requested address>

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I’m trying to setup KiwiTCMS to use it in our local network and I’ve been having trouble setting up e-mail notifications.

I’ve edited *common.py*  according to documentation on a website to look like this:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = myemail
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ‘[Kiwi-TCMS] ‘
...
EMAIL_HOST = smtp.mydomain.com
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password
...
Played around with TLS/SSL settings
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

However, no matter what I do, when I send a test email, I’m always getting this error

```
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address.
```

Command in question: `sudo docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestmail <address>`

I’m using Ubuntu 20.04. Proxy has been configured and machine have access to Internet\local resources.

I’ve tried to send an e-mail using my credentials using powershell on windows and it’s working fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gmail? If you are using gmail, in the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD field you cannot key in your email account login password. YOU have to generate a random password inside your account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).